# telerik radgrid control detail screen not refreshing when click on master record

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have two radgrids on my aspx page: Log and LogDetails.

When I click on a row on Log grid, I would like LogDetails to refresh with the logid of LogGrid. But the details grid **is not refreshing.**

Please help me. Here is my code. Thanks

```
     protected void OnLogGridNeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        var logs = LogManager.FindLog();

        var sortedlogs = from l in logs
                         orderby l.LogId descending
                         select l;

        grdLogGrid.DataSource = sortedlogs;

    }

    protected void OnLogDetailGridNeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        int logid = 0; 

        if (grdLogGrid.SelectedValue != null)
            logid = Convert.ToInt32(grdLogGrid.SelectedValue.ToString());


        var logDetails = LogManager.FindLogDetail();
        var logDetail = from ld in logDetails
                        where ld.LogId == logid
                        select ld;

        grdLogDetailGrid.DataSource = logDetail;

    }

    protected void OnLogGridItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        grdLogDetailGrid.Rebind();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass `LogId` value to details grid better to use `DataKeyNames` property of MasterTableView to set unique identifier property name and `SelectedValue` property of the master RadGrid to get it's value in code-behind. Check this demo: [Grid / Master/Detail Grids](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/selectedvalue/defaultcs.aspx)

As you use advanced data binding you can access SelectedValue property of the master grid just in detail's grid NeedDataSource event handler without handling `ItemCommand` event of the master grid.

Comment: In my OnLogDetailGridNeedDataSource, I was able to get logid by Convert.ToInt32(grdLogGrid.SelectedValue.ToString()).. Now my challenge is to be able to refresh the detail grid when master grid is selected with fresh data.

Comment: Read description for demo that I've suggested carefully.